# Optimize a Combinations of Combinations

Tags: python-3.x, combinations, mathematical-optimization

I need guidance as to if this is possible in Python and how it could be done. I'm trying optimize a lineup of players in a game. Each player has an integer value associated with them based on the skill of their opponent. I'd like to find a way to find the 2 different optimal match ups for the players in a 2v2 game that maximizes their values. For example:

This represents the player's values against different opponent levels.

```
Opponent Level     Elite    Middle     Low
Player Name         
A                   4.2      -3.7      2.6
B                  -5.8      -4.3      1.2
C                   0.6       2.8      9.2      
D                  -7.0       2.3      1.2   
E                   8.0       5.5     -0.6
F                   3.3       4.4      6.6
```

What I'm hoping to achieve is something like this:

```
Match Ups Version 1:
Round 1
Elite   Player A and Player B
Middle  Player C and Player D
Low     Player E and Player F
Round 2:
Elite   Player F and Player C
Middle  Player E and Player B
Low     Player A and Player D
```

Where the match ups maximize the sum of their values. The only constraints are that a player can only be used once per round, and not used against the same opponent level in the next round.

I'm really struggling with theoretically how to do this in Python, so any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand

> Where the match ups maximize the sum of their values.

But I would start the combinations and then do you math on each permutation to come up with each round.

```
from itertools import combinations

df = read_clipboard()
df
```

Out[65]:

```
   Elite  Middle  Low
0
A    4.2    -3.7  2.6
B   -5.8    -4.3  1.2
C    0.6     2.8  9.2
D   -7.0     2.3  1.2
E    8.0     5.5 -0.6
F    3.3     4.4  6.6
```

After setup

```
# Get all the combinations of the players (limit it to two players)
matches = combinations(df.index, 2)
```

Then work through the tuples calculating the values. (This is where it is unclear how the `sum of values` is maximized, so I guessed that you mean to add all 6 values in the matchup together and then sort by largest to smallest).  Yes, it could be done as a comprehension, but I'm trying to be explicit.

```
match = {}
for team1, team2 in matchups:
    match[f'{team1}_{team2}'] = [df.loc[team1].sum() + df.loc[team2].sum()]


df_matches = pd.DataFrame(match).T
df_matches

Out[93]:
        0
A_B  -5.8
A_C  15.7
A_D  -0.4
A_E  16.0
A_F  17.4
B_C   3.7
B_D -12.4
B_E   4.0
B_F   5.4
C_D   9.1
C_E  25.5
C_F  26.9
D_E   9.4
D_F  10.8
E_F  27.2
```

Does this get you started?

Comment: You could just do `matchups = list(combinations(df.index, 2))`

Comment: Updated to remove the list altogether and added output as a df.

Comment: Hi @MichaelD, Sorry for the confusion what I meant by "Where the match ups maximize the sum of their values." I meant, my final goal is I want to maximize the final score of the team where the final score is the sum of each integer value associated with the player based on how they are played. For example, score for Round 1 Matchup 1 would be: 9.5 and Round 1 Matchup 2 would be: 8.8. The Total Round 1 Score would be 18.3 and I would like to maximize the total round 1 score

Comment: @KevinClark the exact math may have to be up to your. Why is the first round first match 9.5?

Comment: @MichaelD So for the first round first match Player A Elite Value + Player B Middle + Player C Middle + Player D Middle + Player E Low + Player F Low = 4.2 + -5.8 + 2.8 + 2.3 + -0.6 + 6.0 = 9.5